# How to upgrade HornetQ version in JBoss 7

Tags: jboss, hornetq

I am using jboss-as-7.1.1.Final which has embedded the hornetQ server version 2.2.13.Final. I want to upgrade the version of hornetQ to 2.3.0 CR1. How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the following link:

https://community.jboss.org/message/796065#796065

The best bet is to wait for AS7.2 which is due shortly and uses CR1.

Comment: one possibility is to use nightly snapshot version of jboss, while waiting for 7.2 to be released.